# How to reduce the width of textfield using jQuery mobile?

Tags: jquery, css, jquery-mobile

Can you please tell me how to reduce the width of a textfield using jQuery mobile?

[Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/BKbZB/)

**Using this CSS it does't work**

```
#co label{
    color: red !important;
    width: 100px !important;
    margin :30px;
}

#co input{

    width: 100px !important;
    border-radius: 0 !important;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

It's the box around the input, that sets the size, and is styled "pretty". So that is what you need to change.

```
#co div.ui-input-text{
    width: 100px;
}
```

**JSFiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/BKbZB/3/**

---

If you want a mixture of default AND small input boxes, you can do:

```
<div data-role="fieldcontain" class="small-input">
    <label >User Name</label>
    <input type="text"   />
</div>
```

CSS:

```
.small-input div.ui-input-text{
    width: 100px;
    padding: 0px 2px;
}
```

**JSFiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/BKbZB/5/**

Comment: But if i create another text field it make only 100 px

Comment: @user1542984 Well I'm sure you have plenty to work with here? Just change the ids, or do whatever you want with others classes. Also that was not your question.

Comment: please check user answer on fiddle if you fill text the text goes outside the box

Comment: there is a bug in your answer please fill the text field it will go outside

Comment: @user1542984 I updated the fiddle afterwards. But honestly, I'm not gonna do everything for you. You have plenty to work with here, and your question is answered. I even updated my answer, so you can differentiate between default and small input boxes.

Comment: @user1542984 Well check the fiddles again, it works just fine. You can  have small and big textboxes as you want, and the input boxes are properly styled.

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/49393/discussion-between-andre-snede-hansen-and-user1542984)

Answer (score 0):

```
 #co .ui-input-text
 {
    width: 100px;
  }
```

Answer (score 0):

Check it... Its Works!

HTML Code

```
   <div data-role="content" id="co">
      <div data-role="fieldcontain">
         <label >User Name</label>
        <input type="text"/>
    </div>
```

CSS Code

```
    #co label{
     color: red !important;
     width: 100px !important;
     margin :30px;
     }
   #co .ui-input-text{
   width: 100px;
   border-radius: 50;
 }
```